# Filter meta tag in <head> based on body class

Tags: php, html, if-statement, filter, meta

I am rather new to .php. I can read most of it a make edits here and there, but writing it is a challenge. I would appreciate any help with this issue I am having.

We have a client who is using a service that references template pages on their wordpress site to dynamically generate their own content. Its a lot to explain, but its basically a Chamber of Commerce website that utilizes this service to handle member-related content based on a user's member level.

All I had to do was create two template pages, and their service would do the rest with the help of a few additions to the DNS.

The issue we are having is that my frontend builder (themify) is placing a meta tag into the `<head>` of the page. This service does not play well with the id's included in the code. 2 examples are given below of the error.

I cannot remove this id or else the css for my frontend builder does not function properly.

What I have in mind to do is create a filter or add an if statement to the line of code that is adding the `<meta>` to the head that will add/remove this meta based on the `<body>` class.

Here is a snippet of the code that places the meta in the `<head>`:

```
public function builder_stylesheet_style_tag($tag, $handle, $href, $media) {
            if ('builder-styles' === $handle) {
                $tag = '<meta name="builder-styles-css" content="" id="builder-styles-css">' . "\n";
            } 

            return $tag;
        }
```

When the template page that has a class of .weblinkTemplate is loaded, I need `id="builder-styles-css"` to be removed. How would I rewrite the above snippet in order to make that happen?

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRCkC.jpg)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECBR6.jpg)

Comment: It seems that you are using "_XHTML 1.0 Strict_" for the document type (defined in the `!DOCTYPE` tag), because it seems that only this document type accepts a _meta_ "id" attribute. The _meta_ tag should then be closed, like `<meta />`, or `<meta></meta>`. Try to somehow close your meta tag. Any change?

Comment: Or just define a HTML5 doctype, e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>` and let the _meta_ be as it is. Because HTML5 should accept a _meta_ attribute "id".

Comment: @dakis Thank you for pointing that out. It is beyond me why I didn't notice the missing closing tag. For the second error, it had a self-closing tag, which I wasn't aware was ok for "<meta>" tags. So just to be sure, I changed it "</meta>" and voila, it loads the page with no errors. I guess I just needed a pair of fresh eyes.

Comment: You are very welcome. By the way, better use this form of closing: `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`. And try to avoid printing html code with php whenever is possible. Good luck.